# trying to run a testsuite for c with on a ruby server and it gives an error

Tags: ruby

---

*** Starting server on port 18000**                   
     **Visit http://localhost:18000 to view testsuite. ***
    *******************************************************
    [2016-06-01 16:44:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2016-06-01 16:44:22] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
    [2016-06-01 16:44:22] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
    [2016-06-01 16:44:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2736 port=18000

```
//after searching through the stackoverflow tried lsof -wni tcp:3000 and kill //-9 2376, didnt help
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it once more did work, dont know what the issue though